# CloudKit reindexing data takes forever

Tags: ios, macos, cloudkit

I have a CloudKit-based app running in production, each user may have on average 1000 items in the main entity of the app. I just added an index to one of the entities in my schema, and after deploy, I get the "reindexing production data" progress in CloudKit Dashboard. That thing has been running for days and shows no sign of stopping.

So I tried adding another index to the main entity in the development CloudKit environment, which has just my data (3000 records). Even this is taking a long time and shows no sign of stopping. Do others have this experience?

Comment: Either not a lot of people use CloudKit in production, or this is a recent problem. Because Googling has not revealed anything except a Twitter post: https://twitter.com/search?q=cloudkit%20reindexing&src=typd and a post today on the Apple forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/29690.

Answer (score 1):

I have been developing an application with CloudKit for the last 6 months. And from about a month in, I have had this reindexing in both Development and Production. Every time I log in, it is still and indeterminate bar. I looked into this 6 months ago and found nothing. I have checked this in multiple browsers (chrome, safari, & firefox) and it is always the same.

My app is live on the store and seems to be unaffected by this.

So I have just ignored it. Not sure if its a UI glitch or if this process has actually been working since July (Which would be pathetic ;))